# php5 converts 64 bit integer to double - how force 64-bit?

Tags: php, int64

in php5, pass a 64bit integer, `1707541557936130` through GET, but it shows value of `1.7075415579361E+15`

how can I force php to use large integers as integers, not as float

when I shift `<<` apparently the result of that is int32 as well, not int64

is there a way to globally say use int64?

Comment: There is [GMP](http://php.net/manual/book.gmp.php) and there is [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/book.bc.php). At least GMP should help you here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP supports 64bit integers only on 64bit systems. In both cases integers, that are larger than PHP_INT_MAX, are converted to floats.
see [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Try this code:

```
<?php
$i=1707541557936130;
var_dump($i);    
echo PHP_INT_MAX;
```

Comment: that's a bummer, esp with PHP's automatic conversion.