# in php5, how to stop GET from (wrongly) converting into numeric?

Tags: php, get, int64

in relation to [php int64 limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701655/php5-converts-64-bit-integer-to-double-how-force-64-bit), if the uri has a int64 argument, how do you prevent GET from wrongly converting it into numeric and simply keeping it as a string?

```
http://some.com?id=1707541557936130
```

then

```
echo $_GET['id'] => 1.7075415579361E+15
```

how to prevent this and have `$_GET['id']` be the *string* `1707541557936130`?

the way `$_GET` works now is unusable.  need to parse `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` myself.  but then never know when php will grab a variable and incorrectly convert again.

NOTE: afaik this will be a problem on 32bit, *not* 64bit php installs.

Comment: Mmh...I get a string from var_dump.

Comment: @Aurelio De Rosa - are you running 32 or 64bit?  only problem on 32bit

Comment: @ccyoung Actually I run a 64bit system.

Comment: Unable to recreate without purposefully triggering (like +0). what is the os, php version, php.ini? something has to be triggering this. Is there a sanitation function happening before you call $_GET? I'm on 32 bit windows (a really slow pc) with no problem using php 5.3.8. It's a string like it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bite the bullet and install 64bit - it's what's on your server anyway

Answer (score 4):

Everyrthing coming out of _GET/_POST/_COOKIE is a string. That data wouldn't be converted to a number unless you did something that forced it to be interpreted as one.

```
echo $_GET['id']; // echoes your big number
echo $_GET['id'] + 0; // forces an int conversion
```

Comment: my php page has `echo $_GET['id']` and it writes `1.7075415579361E+15` - there was nothing to force the coercion

Comment: is your php running 32 or 64bit?  this is _only_ a problem on 32bit

Answer (score 0):

This should get the job done.

```
echo (string) $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: This would get rid of any trailing zeroes, if there was a decimal point in the string...

Comment: results in `1.7075415579361E+15` - the problem is using 64bit int in 32bit php.

Answer (score 0):

If the current solutions are not working you can append a string character to the integer such as

```
http://some.com?id=i1707541557936130
```

Additionally, if it is an issue of how the float is displayed you can use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
$id = (string) number_format($_GET['id']);
echo $id;
```

Comment: yes, thought about prepending the ID with an alpha, just as you suggested.  but soon as you use it, eg, `$id = substr($id,1)`, you never know when php is going to stab you in the back and force a coercion on you.  the `number_format()` does not fly since the precision has already been lost

Comment: What are you doing with the number?  Can you split it from the string into an upper and lower half before you manipulate it?